# grep - match string from the first n lines

Tags: shell, grep, find, xargs, csh

I am trying to find the name of all files within a directory that matches a certain pattern. I have written the following bash command:

`find . -type f | xargs -r -n 25 egrep -l -m 1 'pattern'`

This works fine and provides the desired output.

```
./subdir1/file1
./subdir2/file2
```

However the pattern appears only once and within the first 10 lines of each file. But the above command scans the entire file, which is not necessary (the files are big and number of files in the directory is huge, resulting in a really long execution time).

I have tried to `head` the first 10 lines for each file and then do `grep` with the following command:

`find . -type f | xargs -r -n 25 head -n 10 egrep -l -m 1 'pattern'`

but this ends up printing the 10 lines instead of providing a match.

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: You might simply try `awk '/pattern/ {print FILENAME; exit} NR > 10 { exit }` or similar

Comment: Yes, AWK can scan large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk and GNU find:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME; nextfile} FNR==10{nextfile}' {} +
```

or less efficiently because it's calling awk 1 file at a time instead of in batches like the above, with any awk and any find:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME; exit} NR==10{exit}' {} \;
```

Note that "pattern" isn't a "pattern", it's a `regexp`. The word "pattern" is ambiguous and so best avoided in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe to a `while` loop instead of using `xargs`.
The following command also makes use of `grep`'s `--quiet` switch, which just checks for pattern match and *only* has an effect on the exit code:

```
find . -type f | while read -r -d'' f; do head -n10 $f | egrep -m1 --quiet 'pattern' && echo $f ; done
```

Comment: Thanks. I still got this error `f: Undefined variable`

Comment: are you in a _bash_ shell?

Comment: No, I am on a `csh`

Comment: I see. But you tagged your question with _bash_. My solution works in _bash_.

Comment: Ah I see. Corrected now. Thanks for your answer

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for some of the issues with that script. Also, `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E` and it doesn't make sense to use both `-l` (print the file name) and `--quiet` (don't print anything) in a call to grep.

Comment: thanks Ed, edited the answer to remove `-l` switch and add the `-d` switch to `read`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Create a small script to do `head` and `grep`
2. Call the script using `-exec()` functionality of `find` command

my_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
awk -v file_name="$1" 'NR<=10{print $0, file_name}'   $1 | egrep -l -m 1 'pattern'
```

Command to be executed:

```
find . -type f -exec  ./my_script.sh {} \;
```

---

### Demo for search for number 5 in files.

```
$seq 20 | sort -nr > rev_file.txt 
$seq 20 > file.txt 
$cat test.ksh     
#!/bin/ksh 

 awk -v file_name="$1" 'NR<=10{print $0, file_name}'   $1  | grep -w 5
$find . -type f -exec  ./test.ksh {} \; 
 awk -v file_name="$1" 'NR<=10{print $0, file_name}'   $1  | grep -w 5 ./test.ksh
5 ./file.txt
$cat rev_file.txt 
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
$cat file.txt 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
$
```